# RegEx lazy matching from end of string

Tags: regex

Is it possible to perform lazy matching from the *end* of a string?

Contrived Example:

```
let str = "It's the end of the world as we know it"
let regex = /n.+$/
str.match(regex)         //finds "nd of the world as we know it"
```

Simple enough, it finds 1 or more any character from the end of the string until it finds the last "n" (going backwards).

Now, however, let's say I want it to find 1 or more any character from the end of the string until it finds the first "n" (going backwards).  You would think you could add the 'lazy' quantifier, like this:

```
let regexLazy = /n.+?$/
```

but the result would still be the same:

```
str.match(regex)         //finds "nd of the world as we know it"
```

Is it possible to do lazy matching when starting from the *end* of a string?  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: In your case, `/n[^n]*$/` will do.

Comment: Another trick is to reverse the input string, do the regexp, then reverse the output.  (Probably this is overkill for your simple example.)

Comment: Yep, thank you both for the comments.  I do understand that there are other ways to accomplish the same thing (regex!), but in this case it's more a curiosity as to how/why lazy matching doesn't seem to "work" when matching from the end of the string.

Comment: But regex in these these case processes left to right. In Wiktor's solution the [^n] condition fails  to match end-of-statement for the first "n", but the next "n" matches.

Comment: (n.*)*(n.*?)$
would achieve what you are trying to achieve with lazy quantifier. But because lazy matches can be time consuming, the approach using [^n]* is better when it can be used.